# Delete checked checkboxes in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I am trying to delete checked checkboxes in jQuery, but when i want to get state of checkbox i get error message.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/egbrc6mh/3/)

```
    <div class="control-group">

<label class="checkbox"><input value="0" type="checkbox">Message 0</label>
<label class="checkbox"><input value="1" type="checkbox">Message 1</label>
<label class="checkbox"><input value="2" type="checkbox">Message 2</label>
<label class="checkbox"><input value="3" type="checkbox">Message 3</label>
<label class="checkbox"><input value="4" type="checkbox">Message 4</label>
<label class="checkbox"><input value="5" type="checkbox">Message 5</label>
<label class="checkbox"><input value="6" type="checkbox">Message 6</label>
<label class="checkbox"><input value="7" type="checkbox">Message 7</label>
<label class="checkbox"><input value="8" type="checkbox">Message 8</label>

</div> 


 <button class="btn" type="button" id="deleteAcc">Delete</button>
```

My jQuery code is:

```
$("#deleteAcc").on("click",function(){      
    $(".control-group label.checkbox").each(function(){
        if (this.children(":first").is(':checked')) {
            this.remove();
        }
    }); 
});
```

Comment: You could use `if (this.children[0].checked) this.parentNode.removeChild(this)`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need `each` method. Just select the checked inputs and remove the parents (the label elements containing the checkboxes):

```js
$("#deleteAcc").on("click", function() {
  $(".checkbox input:checked").parent().remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="control-group">

  <label class="checkbox">
    <input value="0" type="checkbox">Message 0</label>
  <label class="checkbox">
    <input value="1" type="checkbox">Message 1</label>
  <label class="checkbox">
    <input value="2" type="checkbox">Message 2</label>
  <label class="checkbox">
    <input value="3" type="checkbox">Message 3</label>
  <label class="checkbox">
    <input value="4" type="checkbox">Message 4</label>
  <label class="checkbox">
    <input value="5" type="checkbox">Message 5</label>
  <label class="checkbox">
    <input value="6" type="checkbox">Message 6</label>
  <label class="checkbox">
    <input value="7" type="checkbox">Message 7</label>
  <label class="checkbox">
    <input value="8" type="checkbox">Message 8</label>

</div>


<button class="btn" type="button" id="deleteAcc">Delete</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

The actual issue is that the `this` context in the `$.each` closure is a reference to the DOM node itself. One way you can fix this by wrapping `this` in `$`:

```
$("#deleteAcc").on("click",function(){
    $(".control-group label.checkbox").each(function(){
        if ($(this).children(":first").is(':checked')) {
            $(this).remove();
        }
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this
http://jsfiddle.net/zp3vwh1j/2/

```
$("#deleteAcc").on("click",function(){
    $("input:checkbox").each(function() {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $(this).parent().remove();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$().ready(function () {
    $('body').on('click', '#deletebtn', function () {

        $("#example1 tr").each(function () {
            var rowSelector = $(this);
            if (rowSelector.find("input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked'))
            {
                //THE MARKUP SHOWING THE ID IS NOT AVAILABLE
                //POST A TABLE ENTRY TO CLEAR UP
                var id = rowSelector.find('td').first().next().html();
                var sendObj = {Id : id};
                //USE JSON OBJECT
                $.ajax({
                    url : "/page.aspx/deleteRecord",//CHANGE TO YOUR URL
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: sendObj,
                    type: "POST",
                    success: function () {
                        alert("entry deleted");
                    }
                });
                rowSelector.remove();
            }
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: This answer would benefit from a bit of explanation, rather than posting only the code. e.g. how this approach differs from what the original poster already tried.